# Dealing with imbalance dataset for multi-label classification

Tags: computer-vision, pytorch

In my case, I’ve 33 labels per samples. The input label tensors for a corresponding image are like [0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0…...33]. And the samples for some labels are quite low and some are high. I'm looking for predict the regression values. So what will be the best approach to improve the prediction? I would like to apply data balancing technique. But so far I found the balancing technique available only for multi-class. I’m grateful to you if you share your best knowledge about regarding my problem or any other idea to improve the performance. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: are you trying to solve a *regression* problem: for each input predict 33 different values? and these values are sparse, but not bounded? please clarify your question

Comment: @Shai Yes you right! That's what I'm trying to do. I would like to generate the 33 prediction values. Thank you so much for your response!

Comment: @Shai Brother, I made a mistake to describe my problem. I changed a bit of my description. Would you please check again?

Answer (score 0):

When using a single.model to *regress* multiple values, it is usually beneficial to *preprocess* the predictions to be in roughly the same range.
Look for example on the way detection models predict (regress) bounding box coordinates: values are scaled and the net predicts only corrections.